# Событие прокрутки LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

Имеется уже заполненный несколькими textview LinearLayout. Как мне отловить событие, когда его прокрутили в начало списка(то есть наверх)?

Comment: я прошу прощения, но разве в LinearLayout можно сделать прокрутку элементов без ScrollView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно прикрепить к соответствующему RecyclerView слушатель прокрутки:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            switch (newState){
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                    LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                    int position = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    //проверить видна ли начальная позиция списка
                    if(position == 0){
                        //требуемые действия
                    }
        }
    });
```